# I want to loop over array and make my loop return function if the name does not exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to loop over the array and make my loop return function or one time string to say the name exist?
this is the error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
var x = arr[i].name;

```
var arr = [
  {id: 1, name: "php"},
  {id: 2, name: "mysql"},
  {id: 3, name: "laravel"},
  {id: 4, name: "codeigniter"},
  {id: 5, name: "wordpress"},
  {id: 6, name: "sql"},
  {id: 7, name: "jquery"},
  {id: 8, name: "javascript"},
];

var string;

function checkemail(arr, string) {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let newname = arr[i].name;

    if (newname !== string) {
      return storename();
    } else {
      console.log("name found")
    }
  }
}
}

console.log(checkemail(arr, "javascript"));
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation/format for your script. Either by hand or (even better) provide a snippet and use the built-in _"Tidy"_ feature.

Comment: What's the problem? Any errors? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: What is `newname`? What is `storename`? What is supposed to happen with `var string`?

Comment: What is your expected result!?

Comment: The code you are showing does not create the error above, var x is nowhere in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the entire array before making a decision on the existence of the element in the array

You are calling `storename` function on the first mismatch of the name and parameter. This will make the function checking the first element and return after calling `storename` function.

**My implementation**

```js
function storename() {
  return 'storename function';
}
var arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "php" },
  { id: 2, name: "mysql" },
  { id: 3, name: "laravel" },
  { id: 4, name: "codeigniter" },
  { id: 5, name: "wordpress" },
  { id: 6, name: "sql" },
  { id: 7, name: "jquery" },
  { id: 8, name: "javascript" },
];

var string;

function checkemail(arr, string) {
  var i;
  let isFound = false;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let newname = arr[i].name;
    if (newname === string) {
      isFound = true;
      i = arr.length; // Item found, you can exit the loop now
      return "name found";
    }
  }
  if(!isFound) {
    return storename()
  }
}


console.log(checkemail(arr, "javascript"));
```

`Array.find` implementation:

You can implement the same logic without using a manual loop by using `Array.find` as below.

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "php" },
  { id: 2, name: "mysql" },
  { id: 3, name: "laravel" },
  { id: 4, name: "codeigniter" },
  { id: 5, name: "wordpress" },
  { id: 6, name: "sql" },
  { id: 7, name: "jquery" },
  { id: 8, name: "javascript" },
];

var string;

function storename() {
  return 'storename function';
}

function checkemail(arr, string) {
  const node = arr.find(item => item.name === string);
  return node ? "name found" : storename();
}


console.log(checkemail(arr, "javascript"));
```